# Why I get an attribute value must be a constant error?

Tags: java

I am getting an error of "attribute value must be constant" although the variable is final.

```
protected final String APP_PACKAGE = abstractPlatform.getPropertiesReader().getPackageName();

    @AndroidFindBy(id = APP_PACKAGE +":id/btnSignUp")
private MobileElement signUpTab;
```

if I initialize APP_PACKAGE with a regular String then I am not getting this error. for example: APP_PACKAGE = "com.company.aa";
APP_PACKAGE is final as you can see so why i am getting this error?
Anything i miss?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties of annotations must be compile-time constants and

```
abstractPlatform.getPropertiesReader().getPackageName();
```

is only resolvable at runtime. This means `APP_PACKAGE` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: is there a way I can make it a compile-time constant besides setting APP_PACKAGE value using a regular string?

Comment: @shay7 You could replace the constant at build-time. One example would be [Maven Templating Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/index.html): "*This plugin is useful to filter Java Source Code if you need for example to have things in that code replaced with some properties values*".